# Función Obtener Iniciales dado un Nombre en Javascript

Tags: javascript, funciones, split

En el siguiente programa cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva las 3 iniciales (de nombre y apellidos)? Si tecleo por ejemplo, Juan Garcia Garcia, tiene que mostrar un `alert` con J.G.G.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="es"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title></title> 
        </head> 
            <body> 
                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var nombre=prompt("Introduce nombre y apellidos");        
                    function devuelveIniciales(){ 
                        var separa=nombre.split(""); 
                        nombre=separa[0].charAt(0)+"." + "" +separa[0].charAt(0)+"." + "" +separa[0].charAt()+"."; 
                        alert("Las iniciales de tu nombre y apellidos son: " +nombre);  
                    } 
                    devuelveIniciales(); 
               </script> 
           </body> 
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí un ejemplo con lo solicitado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
   var cadena = "Juan Perez",
    separador = " ", // un espacio en blanco
    arregloDeSubCadenas = cadena.split(separador); // SEPARA EL NOMBRE EN CADENAS INDIVIDUALES
    
    // IMPRIME EL NOMBRE INGRESADO
    document.write("Nombre Ingresado: ");
    for (x=0;x<arregloDeSubCadenas.length;x++){
      document.write(arregloDeSubCadenas[x] + "  ");
    }
    // IMPRIME LA PRIMERA LETRA DE CADA CADENA 
    document.write("<br/>Iniciales Nombre: ");
    for (x=0;x<arregloDeSubCadenas.length;x++){
        subCadena = arregloDeSubCadenas[x].substring(0, 1);
        document.write(subCadena + " ");
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes separar por espacios, asegurarte que devuelves la primer letra y que
sean mayuscualas:

```js
String.prototype.obtenerIniciales= function(glue){
    if (typeof glue == "undefined") {
        var glue = true;
    }

    var iniciales = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z- ]/g, "").match(/\b\w/g);
    
    if (glue) {
        return iniciales.join('');
    }

    return  iniciales;
};

String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    return this.toLowerCase().replace( /\b\w/g, function (m) {
        return m.toUpperCase();
    });
};

//para probar es un metodo extension del objeto

var inicialesJugador= "Chicharito Herandes".obtenerIniciales();

console.log(inicialesJugador);
```

Comment: y que pasa con "Yvonne de la Rosa"?

Comment: "Yvonne de la Rosa" no la conozco, ha ya se deben agregar casos pero eso ya lo puede complementar @user09b.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/name/nm5970566/ es un caso frontera, pero los apellidos compuestos de varias palabras en castellano se procesan diferente.